# Dynamically display table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm trying to make some sort of "timesheet" where the user inputs 2 dates

[image]

and it calculates each month/year and display on a [combobox](https://gyazo.com/5ef295222735820a25cf2f0f7dbc5623).

I wanted to DYNAMICALLY (no need to refresh the page or anything) update the amount of days and fill the table with `Day Number` and `Day Name(monday,etc..)`

I managed to calculate the amount of days in a month but how can I display my table without reload the page?

***Also maybe `change` isn't the right thing because it will not load first time because the combobox didn't change.***

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dates').change(function() {
        var splitDate = $('#dates').val().split("/");
        var month = splitDate[0];
        var year = splitDate[1];
        var days = daysInMonth(month,year);
        alert(days);
    });

    function daysInMonth(month,year) {
        return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 30px;">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">#</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Day</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Number of Clients</th>
                        <th class="text-center"></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr class="text-center">
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input name="amountOfClients[]" type="number"></td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, not a complete answer, but for your question about change event, try alter your code to smth like this. This way you can trigger the method for the first time

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#dates').change(datesChanged);
   datesChanged();
}

function datesChanged() {
   var splitDate = $('#dates').val().split("/"),
      month = splitDate[0],
      year = splitDate[1],
      days = daysInMonth(month,year);
   console.log("days:", days);
}

function daysInMonth(month,year) {
   return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}
```

For the dynamic build, you can use the [datatables](https://datatables.net/) library, it is simple and fast. Basic principal is that you just give it an object and it parses it to html table